# Java tasks - out of memory

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory

I have this program (multiplication of matrix where is not important get the result):

```
package serie06_ExecutorFramework;

import java.util.Random;

public class Sequenziale {
    public static final int NUM_OPERATIONS = 100000;
    public static final int MATRIX_SIZE = 64;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Random rand = new Random();
        System.out.println("Simulazione iniziata");
        for (int operation = 0; operation < NUM_OPERATIONS; operation++) {
            // Crea matrici
            final int[][] m0 = new int[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
            final int[][] m1 = new int[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
            final int[][] m2 = new int[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];

            // Inizializza gli array con numeri random
            for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++) {
                    m0[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
                    m1[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
                }

            // Moltiplica matrici
            for (int i = 0; i < m0[0].length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < m1.length; j++)
                    for (int k = 0; k < m0.length; k++)
                        m2[i][j] += m0[i][k] * m1[k][j];
        }
        System.out.println("Simulazione terminata");
    }
}
```

to a program that works with the task and uses multi-core, at the end i have to plot the speed-up of the program where

> speed-up= sequency time/parallel time

i did the program in this way:
**the task**

```
package pcepS6;

import java.util.Random;

public class MatrixMoltiplication implements Runnable {
    private final int[][] m0;
    private final int[][] m1;

    public MatrixMoltiplication(int[][] m0, int[][] m1) {
        this.m0 = m0;
        this.m1 = m1;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Random rand = new Random();
        // Inizializza gli array con numeri random
        for (int i = 0; i < S6Esercizio1.MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < S6Esercizio1.MATRIX_SIZE; j++) {
                m0[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
                m1[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
            }

        // Moltiplica matrici
        final int[][] m2 = new int[m0.length][m1.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < m0[0].length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < m1.length; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < m0.length; k++)
                     m2[i][j] += m0[i][k] * m1[k][j];
    }
}
```

**the main**

```
package pcepS6;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class S6Esercizio1 {
    public static final int NUM_OPERATIONS      = 100000;
    public static final int MATRIX_SIZE         = 64;
    private static int numThreads               = 5;
    private static final ExecutorService myExec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);


    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Simulazione iniziata");
        System.out.println("Submit delle tasks ai threads");

        for (int operation=0; operation<NUM_OPERATIONS; operation++) {
            int[][] a = new int[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
            int[][] b = new int[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
            myExec.execute( new MatrixMoltiplication(a, b) );
        }

        //l'executor non accetta piu nessuna ulteriore tasks
        myExec.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Tutte le tasks sono state inviate ai threads");

        while ( !myExec.isTerminated() ) {}
        System.out.println("Tutti i threads hanno finito");

    }
}
```

The problem is that i cannot use just 1 thread to get the time of execution, after 2 thread to get the new time... until 20 thread and so at the end  plot the speed-up with all times.
i cannot do that because if i use a small number of threads, i have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead
limit exceeded  at pcepS6.S6Esercizio1.main(S6Esercizio1.java:39)
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-6" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC
overhead limit exceeded     at
pcepS6.MatrixMoltiplication.run(MatrixMoltiplication.java:25)   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I know that i can use instead of **Executors.newFixedThreadPool** the method **newCachedThreadPool** but in this way i cannot get the time with a specific number of threads. 
it is possible that the assigment is completely wrong?

Comment: You seem to be creating 300k 64x64 int matrices.  Is that right?

Comment: yes  ... this is the assignment

Comment: it's caused by the fact that for every thread you create a matrix (100000 matrixs), which will cause a OutOfMemory

Comment: this i know... but the problem is that every object (task) has this matrix... not every thread. ... how it is possible in this way fix this problem? there is another way to works with the executor frameworks without this problme of memory? i'm thinking to don't insert the matrix in the tasks... but after is impossible works in parallel mode

Comment: Don't create the matrix in `main()` move it inside the thread. Also you'd better not submit all the tasks at once, but only as much as the pool can run imediatelly (use `SynchronousQueue` and `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run only 5 task in the same time, so why would you allocate the space for 100000? It is enough to allocate the matrices only for the running tasks.

In addition, there is no reason to inject the matrices to MatrixMoltiplication, because you don't do anything with those matrices just allocate them. So you can change this

```
new MatrixMoltiplication(a, b)
```

to this:

```
new MatrixMoltiplication()
```

and allocate the matrices only when the Executor schedules them:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        a = new int[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
        b = new int[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];

        // rest of the runnable
```

**Another note that does not relate to your question:**

Instead of making two random matrices with elements from the [0-9] interval (and then multiplying them), you can make it in one step:

```
for (int i = 0; i < S6Esercizio1.MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < S6Esercizio1.MATRIX_SIZE; j++) {
          m0[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10) * rand.nextInt(10);
     }
```

It has the same property as the multiplication product of the two [0-9] random matrix.

Also, it is worth to note that you can not use rand.nextInt(82) because it would have different distribution compared to rand.nextInt(10) * rand.nextInt(10).

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing - “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded” - means that GC has been trying to free the memory but is pretty much unable to get any job done. By default, it happens when the JVM is spending more than 98% of the total time in GC and after the GC less than 2% of the heap is recovered.

It means that your application has exhausted pretty much all the available memory and the GC has repeatedly failed to clean it.

Note that the “GC overhead limit exceeded” error is thrown only when 2% of the memory was freed after several GC cycles. This means that the little the GC was able to clean, will be quickly filled again, thus forcing the GC to restart the cleaning process again.

This forms a vicious cycle where the CPU is 100% busy with the GC and no actual work can be done. End users of the application are facing extreme slowdowns – operations which used to be completed in milliseconds are now likely to take minutes to finish. So the “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded” message is a pretty nice example of a fail fast principle in action.

Fast workaround for this would be increasing the heap size - add (or increase if present) the -Xmx parameter specifying how much heap your application is eligible to use.